# d3 customize tick line (based on nextSibling)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have gaps in my data (on the y-axis), so even though I'd rather use a linear scale, I have to go with an Ordinal scale — so that the holes are not seen.

However, I do want to visually show that the data was not continuous using a different tick marker. The idea here is to check if the `next value - current value` is 1, and if not draw a different tick line.

Using [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4323929) I used `this.parentNode.nextSibling` — but it's not getting the required value.

How can I go about doing this?

Sample code below. I would want the lines for 2, 5 and 8 show up in a different tick (say `stroke-dasharray: "10,2"` or may be a different color)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ticks problem</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <svg width="500" height="300"></svg>

    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var svg = d3.select("svg"),
        margin = {top: 20, right: 0, bottom: 20, left: 0},
        width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      var data = [5, 15, 7, 10, 4, 12, 14];

      var yDomain = [1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 11];
      var yRange  = Array(data.length+1).fill().map((d,i)=>(i+1)*35);
      var yScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
          .domain(yDomain)
          .range(yRange);

      var yAxis = d3.axisRight(yScale)
        .ticks(data.length+1)
        .tickSize(width);

      function customYAxis(g) {
        g.call(yAxis);
        g.attr("id", "y-axis");
        g.select(".domain").remove();
        //g.selectAll(".tick line").attr("stroke", "#777").attr("stroke-dasharray", "2,2");
        g.selectAll(".tick line")
        .attr("stroke", "#777")
        .attr("stroke-dasharray", (d,i)=>{
          //let n = d3.select(this.parentNode.nextSibling).datum(); // not working
          //console.log(i + " " + d+" "+n);
          // return "10,2" if n-d > 1
          return "2,2"; // return some default for now
        })
        g.selectAll(".tick text").attr("x", 4).attr("dy", -4);
      }

      g.append('g').call(customYAxis);
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember, that [`selection.attr()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_attr) will get called providing **three** arguments:

> being passed the current datum (*d*), the current index (*i*), and the current group (*nodes*), with *this* as the current DOM element (*nodes[i]*)

You can make use of the third argument to access the datum of the next element. Since `i` is the index of the current element, `node[i+1]` will point to the next element. You can easily select that next element and use `.datum()` to retrieve the bound datum.

```
d3.select(nodes[i+1]).datum()
```

The only thing left is to employ a safeguard to not read past the last element in the `nodes` array.

```
i < nodes.length - 1 && d3.select(nodes[i+1]).datum()
```

This can directly be used in your `.attr()` setter:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ticks problem</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <svg width="500" height="300"></svg>

    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var svg = d3.select("svg"),
        margin = {top: 20, right: 0, bottom: 20, left: 0},
        width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      var data = [5, 15, 7, 10, 4, 12, 14];

      var yDomain = [1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 11];
      var yRange  = Array(data.length+1).fill().map((d,i)=>(i+1)*35);
      var yScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
          .domain(yDomain)
          .range(yRange);

      var yAxis = d3.axisRight(yScale)
        .ticks(data.length+1)
        .tickSize(width);

      function customYAxis(g) {
        g.call(yAxis);
        g.attr("id", "y-axis");
        g.select(".domain").remove();
        //g.selectAll(".tick line").attr("stroke", "#777").attr("stroke-dasharray", "2,2");
        g.selectAll(".tick line")
        .attr("stroke", "#777")
        .attr("stroke-dasharray", (d, i, nodes) => {
          return i < nodes.length - 1 && d3.select(nodes[i+1]).datum() - d > 1 ? "10,2" : "2,2";
        })
        g.selectAll(".tick text").attr("x", 4).attr("dy", -4);
      }

      svg.append('g').call(customYAxis);
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! While this solves the problem at hand, I would also like to learn a little more about `this` keyword, and how it is generally used in the d3 context (in other words, can the problem be solved by using `this.parentNode` etc?). Is there any documentation/link that you are able to point me to in this regard? Thanks again!

Comment: Things are a bit more intricate than that: the tick's line together with the text label is wrapped in a `g` element which, therefore, is the parent element. You'll have to inspect the internals to get hold of that. As far as I am aware of, there is no documentation on the use of `this` other than the one I quoted. Additionally, you have to be careful with `this` when using arrow functions like you do. Given all that, I'd consider my approach the safe option, but there is for sure much to learn should you feel the need to dig deeper into the source.